# Django giving error when save JSON data in models

Tags: python, jquery, json, django, django-models

I tried this code to save my JSON data to my model that is Mvouchar. But getting this error. I easily get data through cmd but I tried to save this in my model then I get the error, why this happens, I think am doing some minor mistake but can't catch please help if u get my problem

```html
#views.py
@csrf_exempt
def jsdata(request):
    table_data = json.loads(request.POST.get('MyData'))
    print(table_data)
    for data in table_data:
     b_no = request.POST['billno']
     b_details = request.POST['billdetails']
     at = request.POST['amount2']
     record = Mvouchar(bill_no = data.b_no, bill_details = data.b_details,am=data.at)
    record.save()
    return render(request, 'cheque/mvouchar.html', {'msg': 'Data Saved.'})
    
#models.py

class Mvouchar(models.Model):
 related = models.ForeignKey(Signs, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
 bill_no = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True, blank=True)
 bill_details = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
 am = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
 vouchar_no = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
  
#urls.py

url(r'jsondata/$', views.jsdata, name='jsondata'),

#script
<script>
$("#btnjson").click(function () {
   var array1 = [];
     $("tbody tr").each(function () {
                        var firstTableData = {};
                        firstTableData.BillNo = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text();
                        firstTableData.BillDetails = $(this).find('td').eq(1).text();
                        firstTableData.Amount = $(this).find('td').eq(2).text();
                        array1.push(firstTableData);
                    //}
                }); 
    alert(JSON.stringify(array1));
     $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/jsondata/",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {MyData: JSON.stringify(array1)},
    success: function(msg){
                alert(msg);
            }
        });
        return false;
    } );
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post `table_data` that is printing in your console.

Comment: This error probably occurs when the key not present in request data.

Comment: please see my question now i insert image with print table_data

Comment: In this case, it really is uppercase letters as I mentioned in my answer - python dictionary keys are case sensitive. Your dictionary contains `BillNo` but you query for `billno`.

Comment: From your ajax you are sending just one array MyData which contains your json string. How do you expect to get `request.POST['billno']` in your view. It doesn't exists, you never sent it. I think in your ajax you should post `data: JSON.stringify(array1)`, there is no need to put the json in another object.

Comment: there is another good point - you should try to get `data['BillNo']` instead of `request.POST['billno']`

Comment: yeah that would work too, but whats the point of posting json data inside another object, hence making it practically json inside json

Comment: hey @VaibhavVishal i dnt understand what u want to say i know i missing something but could not find out

Comment: Your code should work with the instructions I provided in my answer. Vaibhav just brings up two excellent points (the wrong element to query - see my answer for an expanded explanation) and a possibly easier way to send the data (of which I am not completely sure if I agree - but it is definitely worth a try)

Comment: nvm i see you are sending an array to create multiple objects, so the way you are sending json is alright. I was thinking you are going to create just one object.

Comment: :-) Then I see why I was confused with that suggestion.
@monikachoudhary - I edited my answer to include a code snippet that should solve your issues.

Comment: I also found another issue: There seems to be one space missing before the `record.save()` line - this may be a copy & paste error but it for sure is an indentation error.

Comment: i want to save these array value in three different filleds that's why am doing this now i edited my code and get following error plz check question for trace

Comment: no its my notepad ++ problem that getting like that

Comment: @monikachoudharySorry, my bad, I overlooked that mistake - I corrected my example code accordingly (basically, you could either do the lookup in `data` directly or use the variables (which is what I opted for).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
    def jsdata(request):
        table_data = json.loads(request.POST.get('MyData'))
        # print(table_data)
        r_data = {
            'success': True,
        }
        for data in table_data:
            # Since you are just creating objects you don't need to save created object in a variable.
            try:
                Mvouchar.objects.create(bill_no = data['BillNo'], bill_details=data['BillDetails'],at=data['Amount'])
            except:
                r_data['success'] = False

        # IMO Views responding to ajax requests should send JsonResponse
        if r_data['success']:
            r_data['msg'] = 'Data Saved'
        else:
            r_data['msg'] = 'Not all Data Saved'
        return JsonResponse(r_data)
```

Comment: hey does not show any error now i will fix but still does not save entry in my models

Comment: please see the image in question now no error but at submit data does not submit to my fields

Comment: i get two alert in first alert have my data but in second alert it shows [object Object]

Comment: so what happend with my data why its not connect to models now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182481/discussion-between-vaibhav-vishal-and-monika-choudhary).

Comment: please see the trace

Comment: hi are u their.

Comment: hey please see my recant question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53001915/django-not-null-constraint-failed-while-posting-json-data-to-models

Answer (score 0):

A `KeyError` is usually thrown when you look up a value for a key in a dictionary that does not exist. You could either provide a default value or check the existence of the key before you do the lookup.

```
request.POST.get('billno', 'default_value')
```

For more information about querying a dictionary with default values, see [this helpful StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11041421/1331407)

*The line above as such will not work, since there are other issues in this code besides the key not existing with only lowercase letters (see below).*

Looking at the code I expect the key to not exist either because **it has not been sent or** because **it may contain uppercase letters**.

As it has been pointed out in the comments to your question, not only are you querying for `billno` (only lowercase letters) while the key you send has uppercase letters (`BillNo`), but you also embed it into another dictionary `MyData` - you need to change your query from `request.POST['billno']` to `data['BillNo']` (the same goes for all the other values you are trying to extract).

The correct query would thus look like this:

```
for data in table_data:
    b_no = data['BillNo']
    b_details = data['BillDetails']
    at = data['Amount']
    record = Mvouchar(bill_no = b_no, bill_details = b_details,am=at)
    record.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

This error probably occurs when the key not present in request data. By changing

```
b_no = request.POST['billno']
```

to

`b_no = request.POST.get('BillNo')`.

solve throwing this exception. Even if data not present it returns None. Or can handle it by add try.except block.

```
try:
    b_no = request.POST['billno'] 
except KeyError:
    pass
```

And in your code, you call every dict key in lower case form and amount key as amount2. Change that to Amount

Comment: now its giving me typeError: method 'object' is not subscriptable

Comment: `request.POST.get` is a method, it needs parentheses `()` not square brackets `[]`.

Comment: This also does not take into account that the key is not sent in `request.POST` but within a dictionary within a list within the key `request.POST['Mydata']` instead...

Answer (score 0):

If your are storing data in `table_data` (`table_data = request.POST.get('MyData')`) then use `table_data` to store it in models.

Your data is in dictionary form so need to call values by its keys.
like  -

```
@csrf_exempt
def jsdata(request):
    table_data = json.loads(request.POST.get('MyData'))
    print(table_data)
    for data in table_data:
        b_no = data.get('BillNo')
        b_details = data.get('BillDetails')
        at = data.get('Amount')
        record = Mvouchar(bill_no = b_no , bill_details = b_details ,am=at )
       record.save()
    return render(request, 'cheque/mvouchar.html', {'msg': 'Data Saved.'})
```

Try this and tell me if any error occurs.

Comment: hey @PankajSharma now am also getting error plz check trace in updated question

Comment: @monikachoudhary I can't understand which is current error trace and what updates you have made in your views.py

Comment: In which attribute you are getting error ? Also can post new question for this error